# Flowgarithm for common child program for a beginner (without pointers)

Tags: arrays, strings, longest-common-substring

I'm a first year BCA student. Can you help me with flowgarithm of the common child problem (LCS) without pointers

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify your question and what you are asking.  What is the "common child problem"?  Typically a good way to specify an algorithm problem is to list the inputs to the algorithm and the desired output.  What does "without pointers" mean?  What is a "flowgarithm"?  Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor?

Comment: By flowgarithm i mean flowchart with decison symbol , process symbol etc. Common child problem is the lowest common substring problem

Comment: Edit the question. Explain in details what you mean by flowgarithm, LCS, and where you are stuck.